# jqgrid resizeStop not firing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Why doesn't `resizeStop` get called after I resize a jqgrid table?

Here is my function:

```
resizeStop: function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

I don't get any js errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) says resizeStop is fired when a column is resized. Not the Grid

Comment: Right, I just noticed that after hours of searching. Do you know how to make it work when the table is resized?

Comment: Thank you Manuel. I just figured it out. I used `gridResize` and passed in `stop` as an option with a function. `gridResize` is a plugin for JqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to show emails in grid as list and on click any email, wanted to show preview in a div.

both needed to be resizeable.

Naturally I thought resizeStop will do the trick at the end of grid resize but it didnt work

I then used the below work around to make it work

The jqgrid renames the grid element with a prefix gbox_

so my demolist grid became gbox_demolist.
then I simply used standard jquery resizestop

my grid was

```
$(#demolist).jqgrid{
....
}
```

after grid is initilized

```
$("#gbox_demolist").bind( "resizestop", function(event, ui) { 
alert($("#gbox_demolist").width() );
//do whatever you want
});
```